# Are hadoop and informatica related?

Tags: hadoop, informatica

I am new to the hadoop technology. By reading few blogs I was wondering whether hadoop and informatica are related or not?

Answer (score 0):

Informatica is a ETL tools that performs data cleaning and transformation. New Informatica tools has facility to connect to various hadoop cluster HDFS and other tools in hadoop ecosystem